# Running the scheduler twice is updating the file with the earlier file in Console application C#

Tags: c#, excel, console-application

I have a requirement where my scheduler will run twice in a day. One in the morning and a second time in evening. When I run my current code it stores the file in a folder.

So again when I run the same application in the evening what happens is that the same file which is saved earlier in the morning is getting updated again which I don't want to happen. I want to save both the files. So what should I do?

Below is my current code. Please give me suggestions

```
public void ExportExcel(string strWorkbookName, DataSet ds)
    {   
        string strDateFolder = "";
        string strFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"].ToString();

        try
        {
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                strDateFolder = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

                if (Directory.Exists(strDateFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(strDateFolder);
                }

                wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
                wb.SaveAs(ConfigurationRead.GetAppSetting("ReportDirectory") + "\\" + strDateFolder + "\\" + strFileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Also, I want to delete the folder created after 7 days..Is that also possible ?

Comment: So your file in the evening is overwriting the one from the morning because they use the same `dd-MM-yyyy` folder name and the same filename from the `AppSettings["FileName"]`?  Am I missing something because that seems rather a straightforward problem?

Comment: @Trevor: Yes u r correct, its happening what you told me. Is there any solution for this

Comment: @BNN yes. You could for example add a timestamp to the filename.

Comment: @FLeX: timestamp on what, folder of file ?

Comment: @BNN that depends on if you want both the files in the same folder. I would add it to the filename.

Comment: @BNN You can add a timestamp (such as the hour of the day in 24-hour format) to either the folder name or the filename or both.  It would depend on what is using these files that you are creating.  We don't have enough information to answer that for you.

Comment: I am trying like this `string strFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"].ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString();`

Comment: @FLeX Would you like to write this one up?

Comment: @Trevor looks like King of the North covered it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strDateFolder will contain the same value through both runs because it gets the date. You may want to add time to that so it creates another file. Like this:

```
strDateFolder = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh");
```

Then, the code below is like saying: if this directory exists, create it.

```
if (Directory.Exists(strDateFolder))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(strDateFolder);
}
```

You can use only this, because it will create it only if it does not exist:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(strDateFolder);
```

**Update from post:**
This would delete your folders older that 6 days

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string path = ConfigurationRead.GetAppSetting("ReportDirectory");
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
     string folderPath = s.Remove(0, path.Length);
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(folderPath, "dd-MM-yyyy hhmmss", enUS, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime td))
     {
          if (td <= currentDate)
          {
               Directory.Delete(s, true);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: didnt got ur logic.  Please explain a bit.where to add and how to implement

Comment: Updated answer  .

Comment: getting error at `out DateTime td` as `system.datetime is a type but used as a variable`

Comment: @BNN try changing `out DateTime td` to `out td`

Comment: @FLeX: getting error as `the best overloaded method match for system.datetime.parseexact has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @BNN the code i posted should be running fine. I tested before posting. Try pasting the code in a new project to see if you are still getting the same issue.

Comment: @FLeX: how would the compiler know what the variable td is if you don't declare it? you either declare it outside the out param scope or use it as it is.

Comment: @KingoftheNorth yeah, I messed up. Sorry about that.